# How can I resolve the Paperclip conflict with RightAWS and AWS-S3 gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, paperclip, right-aws

I *must* use RightAWS for certain things. However, I can only get Paperclip uploads to S3 working when RightAWS is nowhere in my Gemfile. Since v2.3.11, Paperclip has used AWS-S3, switching from RightAWS.

RightAWS allows me to check the existence of an object *without* downloading the entire object via the head? method. It also allows me to stream massive amounts of files from a bucket in 1,000 unit chunks with its incrementally_list_bucket method. I haven't found a way to duplicate this functionality in AWS-S3. I do not have the time currently to implement this and contribute it either.

Can anyone tell me if there is a way to load both of these AWS gems in a Rails 3 project without causing Paperclip to cause the "wrong number of arguments (4 for 5) error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ta dahhh. Changing my Gemfile from:

```
gem 'aws-s3'
```

to:

```
gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'
```

fixed the problem!